# can we get the penultimate exception that occurred from an mdmp or hdmp in windbg

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windbg

I got a crash dump (both mdmp and hdmp) for my application (written in C++) captured using dr. watson.
After analyzing the dumps through windbg, I concluded that the crash had occurred in the `catch()` itself :)

What I need to know is what exception caused the the failure in the first place i.e. I need that penultimate(last but one th) exception that had occurred.

I know I could get the same by some other ways, but is there a specific command with which we could get the list of errors\exceptions occurring from the dump file.

Thanks.

--Samrat Patil

Answer (score 1):

what i usually do is issue the search command looking for specific CONTEXT flags:

```
s-d esp l10000 1003f
```

the search is usually performed with the current value of **esp** as a starting point.
Once you're lucky you get back a bunch of addresses on stack you can further use as parameters for `.cxr`. The addresses (if several) can be followed to trace the exception flow.

Once the new context is set, it is usually trivial to see where a particular exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

isn't `!analyze -v` working for you?